# Активация автоматической расстановки переноса слов в документе

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

Как включить автоматическую расстановку переноса слов (`c# docx`)? Каким методом воспользоваться (`DocX.Paragraph`?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается такой возможности нет! Вот ответ официального представителя `Xceed` по возможностям `DocX`:

> Text hyphenation is not currently supported in Xceed Words for .NET. I
> have submitted a feature request case to the development team. We will
> get back to you with their feedback as soon as we have it available.
> We appreciate your patience and understanding. Thank you.

Возможные пути решения проблемы - я лично выбираю расположение текста по ширине страницы, пока лучшего не придумал.